# RenderThread SIGABRT

Tags: android, crash

I'm receiving a native crash using a shared element transition between activities, but only for Android 8.1 and on Google devices (Pixel, Pixel 2, Nexus 6P, etc...):

```
pid: 20499, tid: 22683, name: RenderThread  >>> [APPNAME] <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'sp<> assignment detected data race'
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   000000000000589b  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
    x4   0700007411003135  x5   0700007411003135  x6   0700007411003135  x7   3531ffffffffffff
    x8   0000000000000083  x9   0000000010000000  x10  0000007214bf4ca0  x11  0000000000000001
    x12  0000007214bf4dc0  x13  ffffffffffffffff  x14  ffffffffffff0000  x15  ffffffffffffffff
    x16  0000005c0f077fa8  x17  00000072b09c752c  x18  0000000000000008  x19  0000000000005013
    x20  000000000000589b  x21  0000000000000083  x22  00000072249f1f40  x23  00000072249f1f58
    x24  0000007214717590  x25  00000072248393a0  x26  00000072118d9220  x27  0000007214bf5350
    x28  0000007214bf5300  x29  0000007214bf4ce0  x30  00000072b097c760
    sp   0000007214bf4ca0  pc   00000072b097c788  pstate 0000000060000000
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000000000001d788  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+120)
    #01 pc 0000000000007f08  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+296)
    #02 pc 0000000000010af4  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::sp_report_race()+28)
    #03 pc 00000000000fdd08  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::RootRenderNode::detachAnimators()+320)
    #04 pc 00000000000fbcac  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AnimationContextBridge::destroy()+24)
    #05 pc 000000000006fbd0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::Bridge_destroy(android::uirenderer::renderthread::destroyArgs*)+12)
    #06 pc 00000000000718fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::MethodInvokeRenderTask::run()+24)
    #07 pc 0000000000071c70  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::SignalingRenderTask::run()+28)
    #08 pc 0000000000072a58  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+336)
    #09 pc 0000000000011478  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
    #10 pc 00000000000a9814  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
    #11 pc 0000000000067d80  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    #12 pc 000000000001ec18  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

It crashes also if the app is on background. How can I solve this? It seems to happen only if the Hardware Acceleration is enable, but I really need it enabled on my app.

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm getting the following, linked I think to using a custom RemoteViews within a Notification
07-28 09:24:00.328 21108-21135/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 21135 (RenderThread), pid 21108 (e.tm.free.debug)

Comment: Same problem here, but it happens from Android 6 to Android 8.1

Comment: In the end I figure out that there were 2 animations running at the same time, so I had to modify one of them slightly so that they are not in race between them anymore.
I'm afraid it's the only way to solve it until Android team will fix the issue on the native library

Comment: I got same issues, it happened randomly. I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: @ene It happens randomly because it is a race condition: 2 animations are running at the same time on the same object.
You can fix it by disabling or delaying one of them (to be sure it runs when the other has been completed).

Comment: @darkalbo How do u know there is 2 animations are running at the same time? I try to add below code before start animation. The crash still happened with a small probability. ```
            if (mExposureDrawable.isRunning()){
                mExposureDrawable.stop();
            }
            mExposureDrawable.start();```

Answer (score 5):

I was having same issue with an AnimatedVectorDrawable set as a background of an ImageView. So basically i was showing the same animation in different rows of a recyclerview but using same object of AnimatedVectorDrawable, which lead to this crash. I solved it by creating separate objects for separate ViewHolders.

Answer (score 3):

Saw the same native stack sometimes when (inadvertently) trying to restart an animation loop for an AnimatedVectorDrawable after (or perhaps while) trying to pause an Activity.

For reference, the animation loop was this:

```
((Animatable2)animatable).registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
        animatable.start();
    }
});
```

When toggling away from the app, this was logged:

```
W/WindowManager: Unable to start animation, surface is null or no children.
```

Followed by a similar native stack for a race condition:

```
A/DEBUG: backtrace:
A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000021abc  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000000080f8  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+296)
A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000000f26c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::sp_report_race()+28)
A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000010d698  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::RootRenderNode::detachAnimators()+320)
A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000010b768  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AnimationContextBridge::destroy()+24)
A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000005d211c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::destroy()+124)
A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000005d5550  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (std::__1::packaged_task<void ()>::operator()()+88)
A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000000005870b0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+168)
A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00000000001fd60c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+244)
A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000000000083114  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

This has stopped the problem - it should have been there all along in the Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    animatable.stop();
}
```